# Custom Python Wordle game not showing colors correctly

Tags: python, prettytable, colorama

```
from requests import get
from json import loads
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from colorama import Fore
from os import system


def select_game_word():
    """This function will return a random 5-letter word"""
    response = get("https://random-word-api.vercel.app/api?words=1&length=5")
    word = loads(response.text)[0].upper()

    return word


def verify_guessed_word(guessed_word):
    """This function will return a boolean value if the guessed word is verified or not"""

    if len(guessed_word) == 5:
        response = get(f"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/{guessed_word}")

        if response.status_code == 200:
            return True

    return False


def ask_guessed_word():
    """This function will return the guessed word from the user"""

    guessed_word = input("Type in your word: ").upper()

    while not verify_guessed_word(guessed_word):
        print("Invalid word. Please try again.")
        guessed_word = input("Type in your word: ").upper()

    return guessed_word


def get_guessed_word_colors(guessed_word, selected_word):
    """This function will return a list of colors for each letter in the guessed word"""

    letter_index_pairs = [] # This list will store key-value pairs for the letters and their indexes.
    
    # Getting all the green letters from the word first
    
    for i in range(0, 5):
        if guessed_word[i] == selected_word[i]:
            selected_word = selected_word.replace(guessed_word[i], "-") # replacing the green letters to dashes so that yellow letters can't pair with them

            letter = Fore.GREEN + guessed_word[i] + Fore.RESET
            letter_index_pairs.append({i: letter})
    
    # This loop will get all the yellow and gray letters from the word next
    for i in range(0, 5):
        if selected_word[i] != "-": # not allowing dashes
            if guessed_word[i] != selected_word[i] and guessed_word[i] in selected_word: # yellow letter checking
                letter = Fore.YELLOW + guessed_word[i] + Fore.RESET
                letter_index_pairs.append({i: letter})

            else: # otherwise considering the letter as grey
                letter = Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + guessed_word[i] + Fore.RESET
                letter_index_pairs.append({i: letter})

    letter_index_pairs = sorted(letter_index_pairs, key=lambda d: list(d.keys())[0]) # Sorting the pairs by their index in the word
    
    # getting the finalized guessed words colors
    guessed_word_colors = []
    for pair in letter_index_pairs:
        guessed_word_colors.extend(list(pair.values()))

    return guessed_word_colors


def get_game_table():
    """This function will get a table for the game"""

    table = PrettyTable()
    table.header = False

    return table


def add_guessed_word_to_table(table, guessed_word_colors):
    """This function will add the colored guessed word onto the game table"""
    table.add_row(guessed_word_colors)
    print(table)


def is_correct_word(guessed_word, selected_word):
    """This function will return a boolean value if the guessed word is correct"""

    if selected_word == guessed_word:
        return True

    return False


def game():
    print("Welcome to Wordle Unlimited!")

    selected_word = "NANNY"
    table = get_game_table()

    chance_number = 0

    while chance_number != 6:
        guessed_word = ask_guessed_word()

        guessed_word_colors = get_guessed_word_colors(guessed_word, selected_word)
        add_guessed_word_to_table(table, guessed_word_colors)

        if is_correct_word(guessed_word, selected_word):
            print(f"Correct! The word was: {selected_word}")
            print(f"You got it on chance #{chance_number}!")

            quit()

        else:
            chance_number += 1

    print(f"You ran out of chances! The word was: {selected_word}")


game()
```

I'm programming a custom Python Wordle game. It was working great, until I came across this issue.

For example, when the correct word to guess is "NANNY" and the user guesses "DEALT" it works perfectly; D, E, L, and T are considered grey letters and A is considered a yellow letter:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbPLb.png)

However, when the user guesses a word like "NORTH" I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\hasee\OneDrive\Documents\wordle unlimited\main.py", line 123, in <module>
    game()
  File "C:\Users\hasee\OneDrive\Documents\wordle unlimited\main.py", line 109, in game
    add_guessed_word_to_table(table, guessed_word_colors)
  File "C:\Users\hasee\OneDrive\Documents\wordle unlimited\main.py", line 84, in add_guessed_word_to_table
    table.add_row(guessed_word_colors)
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\prettytable\prettytable.py", line 1407, in add_row
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 3!=5 (expected)
```

I expected it to show 'N' as green, and the rest grey. I went through `guessed_word_colors()` and couldn't work out why this error is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a cleaned up version of your code that works.  Note that I have removed the prettytable stuff, but it should be easy for you to add this in:

```
def ask_guessed_word():
    return input("Type in your word: ").upper()

def get_guessed_word_colors(guessed_word, selected_word):
    letter_index_pairs = ['']*len(selected_word)
    selected_word = list(selected_word)
    
    # Getting all the green letters from the word first
    
    for i in range(len(selected_word)):
        if guessed_word[i] == selected_word[i]:
            selected_word[i] = "-" # replacing the green letters to dashes so that yellow letters can't pair with them
            letter_index_pairs[i] = "[[" + guessed_word[i] + "]]"
    
    # This loop will get all the yellow and gray letters from the word next
    for i in range(len(selected_word)):
        if guessed_word[i] in selected_word: # yellow letter checking
            letter_index_pairs[i] = " [" + guessed_word[i] + "] "
        elif selected_word[i] != '-':
            letter_index_pairs[i] = "  " + guessed_word[i] + "  "

    return letter_index_pairs


def get_game_table():
    return []


def add_guessed_word_to_table(table, guessed_word_colors):
    """This function will add the colored guessed word onto the game table"""
    table.append(guessed_word_colors)
    for row in table:
        print(row)


def is_correct_word(guessed_word, selected_word):
    return selected_word == guessed_word


def game():
    print("Welcome to Wordle Unlimited!")

    selected_word = "NANNY"
    table = get_game_table()

    for chance_number in range(6):
        guessed_word = ask_guessed_word()

        guessed_word_colors = get_guessed_word_colors(guessed_word, selected_word)
        add_guessed_word_to_table(table, guessed_word_colors)

        if is_correct_word(guessed_word, selected_word):
            print(f"Correct! The word was: {selected_word}")
            print(f"You got it on chance #{chance_number+1}!")
            return

    print(f"You ran out of chances! The word was: {selected_word}")

game()
```